# How to save input memory for keras layers?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Specifically, can I save the memory of input by "reusing" them especially in prediction procedure?

Considering the following scenarios:

case 1:

```
... # net = previous_layer
net = Conv2D(64, 3)(net)
net = Conv2D(64, 3)(net)
net = Conv2D(64, 3)(net)
...
```

case 2:

```
... # net = previous_laeyr
net1 = Conv2D(64, 3)(net)
net2 = Conv2D(64, 3)(net1)
net3 = Conv2D(64, 3)(net2)
...
```

Will case1 save some memory of input by reusing them? I'm about to processing large image (pixel-wise) so I am thinking about saving the memory of input. I've done the training block-wise and I'd like to load the whole image at once for prediction instead of cutting into blocks. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If your network is linear like that, then yes, re-use your variables as in case 1. This would be just like a Sequential model (whereas you're using keras functional). However, many networks use some layers' outputs many times; one layer's output may become the input to more than one future layer, in which case the relevant layers would need unique variables as in case 2.